# ggplot dropping zeros from boxplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2, statistics

Hi from reading and playing around with some data it seems that ggplot might drop zeros when it does plots like boxplots. Apparently it has some problems when handling zeros in log scale. When I do boxplots I constantly get warnings. The second I assume are removal of NAs but the first looks like it might be dropping zeros

```
Removed x rows containing non-finite values (stat_boxplot)
Removed x rows containing missing values (stat_summary)
```

for example

```
library(ggplot2)

df = read.table(text="X1 X1.1 X1.2 X1.3 X2 X2.1 X2.2 X2.3
        1    0   3    4    3   2    3    1
        2    'NA'   5    5    5   2    1    2
        2     'NA'   2    1    2   1    2    5", header=TRUE)

dfmelt<-melt(df)

 ggplot(dfmelt, aes(variable, value, fill=variable)) +
 geom_boxplot() +
 theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle=90))+
 scale_x_discrete(labels=c('C1','C2','C3','C4','C5','C6','C7','C8'))+
 scale_fill_manual(values=rep(c("red","green","blue","yellow"),2))+
 stat_summary(fun.y = median, geom = "point", position =     position_dodge(width = .9))+
 scale_y_log10()
```

I was wondering if this only happens when doing a log scale? If this could possibly affect the boxplot itself in both its positioning and median? Could data with several zeros and nonzero values have all the zeros dropped shifting the box? And if so how to best handle it so ggplot doesn't end up distorting my data?

thanks

Comment: You can't take a `log` from `0`. Type `log10(0)` in the console and it will return `-Inf`.

Comment: I was transforming (log) my data prior to the box plot. It seems there should be warnings about dropping the data (in my case, the values were already `-Inf` after the transformation. I spotted the problem because my box plots have an "n=" on them which was different. My solution was to take `log(x+1)` during the transformation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

0 is undefined for log scale which is most likely ggplot gets rid of them. There is simply no way mathematically to represent 0 in log scale.

Comment: For series that take integer values, however, `log(x + 1)` is often a reasonable alternative. Event counts are one example.

Comment: okay but if you have a mix of zero and nonzero values the box and the median notch is going to be in the wrong position if the zeros are all dropped right? How can you handle that? I get that you cant represent zero itself but is it statistically acceptable to simply drop all the zero values from a data group and do your boxplot with the remaining nonzero values? Wouldn't that mess up the box plot? It just seems weird to me that this is the default behavior with no easy workaround.

Comment: I would not represent a series like that in log scale, but If I really do want to do it I would use ulfelder's approach of adding 1 to the existing data. And regarding the messing up of the boxplot it's the least messy you can so as the mean of log(c(0,1, 1)) is minus infinity. Try ```mean(log(c(0,1,0)))``` which will illustrate this. In my opinion ggplot does what it should, or at least the minimum amount of damage. :)